# Powers of 3 for a given a positive integer A

Tags: java, algorithm, math, data-structures

Given a positive integer A, return an array of minimum length whose elements are powers of 3 and have the sum of all the elements equal to A.

For input A = 13:

- 3<sup>0</sup> = 1, 3<sup>1</sup> = 3, 3<sup>2</sup> = 9.
- 1 + 3 + 9 = 13.

So A = 13 can be represented as the sum of 1, 3 and 9.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
public static int[] getSolve(int A) {

    List<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<>();
    while (A > 0) {
        int r = A % 3;
        binary.add(r);
        A /= 3;
    }

  //  System.out.println(binary.toString());
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.size(); i++) {
        if (binary.get(i) != 0) {
            while (j < binary.get(i)) {
                res.add((int) Math.pow(3, i));
                j++;
            }
            j =0;
        }
    }
    return res.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Since you have an implementation that works and are asking an open-ended question about improvements, this question would be more suitable to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What version of 'better' are you looking for? Are you looking for efficiency or clarity/simplicity/elegance? Those things will definitely be in tension in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is always the base 3 representation, which is also known as ternary.

My biggest suggestion is that there is no need for your `binary` data structure.  As you are finding the remainders, right there and then you can see whether the remainder is and add the appropriate powers of 3 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## For python folks, it can be useful

class Solution:
# @param A : integer
# @return a list of integers
def solve(self, A):
bits = []
solution = []

```
    while(A != 0):
        bits.append(A % 3);
        A = A // 3;
    
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        if(bits[i] != 0):
            tmp = 0;
            while(tmp < bits[i]):
                solution.append(pow(3, i));
                tmp = tmp + 1
    return solution
```